# finding out all the entities in a table C#

Tags: c#, azure, entity, azure-storage

I am using Microsoft Azure and I am trying to find out all the entity(s) that I have in my table. Unfortunately, I do not know the specifics of these entity(s). I've read through http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/ and it appears most of the entity's they know the specifics of them. For example, they know that it will be a person.

Is there a way to go through all the entity's of my table without knowing the specifics of them?

The reason I am wanting to do this is because I eventually want to find out how much memory my tables are using and I assume I will first need to go through each entity to find how much memory is used for it. Here's the code I have so far:

```
static double CalculateTableMemoryUsage()
        {
            double memory = 0;
            try
            {
                var storageAccount = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
                CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

                CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("mytable");
                table.CreateIfNotExists();
                //I've successfully created the table. Any idea how I can look 
                // through the entity(s) of that table though?


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }


            return memory;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to go through all the entity's of my table without
>   knowing the specifics of them?

Yes. Storage client library has something called `DynamicTableEntity` so you can fetch entities as `DynamicTableEntity` from table. As they name suggests, you don't really need to know the schema in case of a dynamic table entity. Here's a sample code to do so:

```
    static void ListAllEntities()
    {
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(StorageAccount, StorageAccountKey), true);
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("mytable");
        List<DynamicTableEntity> entities = new List<DynamicTableEntity>();
        TableContinuationToken token = null;
        do
        {
            var result = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery(), token);
            token = result.ContinuationToken;
            entities.AddRange(result.Results);
        } while (token != null);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Entities Fetched: " + entities.Count);
    }
```

For calculating the size of an entity, you may find this blog post useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/30/how-the-size-of-an-entity-is-caclulated-in-windows-azure-table-storage.aspx